# Use PrimeReact Themes with CSS Modules Enabled in React Application

Tags: css, reactjs, themes, react-css-modules, primereact

I have enabled [CSS modules within webpack.config](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) in my React application so that I can locally scope CSS files to individual components.  I'm also trying to use the TabView component from [PrimeReact](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/tabview).  When I do so the themes from PrimeReact are not applied.  If I create a separate project and do not enable CSS modules the themes apply correctly.

**How can I use PrimeReact themes and enable CSS modules?**

I've tested moving the content located in Tabs.js directly into App.js and get the same results.

***CSS Modules Enabled***

**Webpack.config**

```
require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash_base64:5]'
            },
          },
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './App.css';
import Tabs from './UI/Tabs';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Tabs/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Tabs.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {TabView, TabPanel} from 'primereact/components/tabview/TabView';
import classes from 'primereact/resources/primereact.css';
import theme from 'primereact/resources/themes/cupertino/theme.css';

const Tabs = () => (
        <TabView>
        <TabPanel header="Tab One">
          This is content for Tab One.
          </TabPanel>
           <TabPanel header="Tab Two">
          This is content for Tab Two.
          </TabPanel>
        </TabView>
);

export default Tabs;
```

**Default React Global CSS Scoping**
[image]

**CSS Modules Enabled (Local Component Scoping)**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use CSS modules and selectively apply global scoping to PrimeReact's themes by modifying webpack.config as follows below.

**Original**:

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
```

**Modified**:

```
 {
            test: /\.css$/,
            //Exclude 3rd party css that needs to be scoped globally from using
            //css-loader with modules enabled
            exclude: [
              path.resolve('node_modules/primereact/resources/primereact.css'),
              path.resolve('node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/cupertino/theme.css'),
            ],
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash_base64:5]'
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          //Additional css-loader configuration
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            //Inlcude only 3rd party css that needs to be scoped globally to use
            //css-loader with modules disabled
            include: [
              path.resolve('node_modules/primereact/resources/primereact.css'),
              path.resolve('node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/cupertino/theme.css'),
            ],
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
```

Comment: Did you find a way to swap themes on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below two npm commands to install the CSS and Style loader:

npm install style-loader - You can add the Version of the loaded if required
npm install css-loader

You are not required to change anything else.